# JQuery Click does not effect window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a trouble to fire `window.onload` event when I clicked, seem it doesn't work to me.

For example, when I clicked checkbox they will call function to render iframe with content. If you uncomment line 2 `callOnLoad()`, the iframe will be loaded with content, but this is not what I expect, I expect when the checkbox checked, the content in iframe will be rendered.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/baonguyen/s0aa6a6q/7/)

Comment: so you want that iframe will show on window load and text appear when check-box clicked?

Comment: There is no event onload if you click the checkbox. onload only fired if you enter the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want below thing:-

***iframe will show on page-load(or on window-load),but the text appear/disappear when check-box checked/unchecked?***

If yes do like below:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cgv" />
        <div id="foo"></div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    callOnLoad();
    $('#cgv').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($('#cgv:checked').length !== 0) {
            $('#iframe').contents().find("body").append('Test <br/>' + new Date());
        } else {
            $('#iframe').contents().find("body").html('');
        }
    });
});
// Function render iframe
function callOnLoad() {
    $("#foo").append("<div id=\"div-parent\"><iframe id=\"iframe\"></iframe></div>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks `Alive to Die`, your nickname make me scare...LOL...it's such a smart way to deal with my  issue, but the point is those iframe was not rendered from my server, it rendered from another source, we cannot edit or change iframe, it will cause  `Blocked a frame with origin "my server url" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: @MikeNguyen  if iframe  coming through third-party then you can't do anything at your end. Sorry but true

Answer (score 1):

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/s9qk1tmk/#&togetherjs=GdkIlGJju8)

JS:

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
  $('#cgv').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('#cgv:checked').length !== 0) {
      callOnLoad(); // Load iframe here, iframe does not work, the content does not render
    } else {
      $('#div-parent').remove(); // Remove div,
    }
  });
});

// Function render iframe
function callOnLoad() {
  $("#foo").append("<div id=\"div-parent\"><iframe id=\"iframe\" class=\"active\"></iframe></div>");
  var iframe = $("#foo").find('[id="iframe"]');
iframe.contents().find("body").append('Test <br/>' + new Date());

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cgv" />
  <div id="foo">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks RonyLoud, I did not test it yet, but it's quite smart way to deal with my issue...but the point is this iframe was rendered from another URL, we cannot append any content will cause cross context iframe...bla bla...